# Client, server and rmi don't work

Tags: java, client, rmi, rmiregistry

This code doesn't work. Well, it works, but the client doesn't print. Am i doing something wrong? I'm using W7 and NetBeans. Is there a way to see if the rmiregistry is ok? If i remove these catch, i can't compile it. I'm pretty sure that problems come from rebind and lookup.

ServerNew.java:

```
    interface C extends Remote
    {
        public String now() throws RemoteException ;
    }

    class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements C
    {    
        public String now() throws RemoteException 
        {
            return "99:99";
        }

        Server() throws RemoteException 
        {

        }

    }

    public class ServerNew
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server=new Server();
        System.setSecurityManager(new java.rmi.RMISecurityManager());
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/time", server);
    }
}
```

ClientNew.java:

```
        interface C extends Remote
    {
        public String now() throws RemoteException ;
    }

    public class ClientNew
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        C server=(C) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/time");
        String text=server.now();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Output for Server (`ServerNew.java:38` is `Naming.rebind`):

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:574)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at servernew.ServerNew.main(ServerNew.java:38)
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:61881" "accept,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkAccept(SecurityManager.java:1174)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.checkAcceptPermission(TCPTransport.java:654)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.checkAcceptPermission(TCPTransport.java:293)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:176)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that exception handling it is impossible for anybody to answer your question. I suggest you fix it and provide the exception that is being thrown. What you have posted so far is completely pointless and should never have been written.

Comment: @AsAs So what part of the exception don't you understand?

Comment: Well, i just started the topic yesterday, so i don't know how to fix.

Comment: @AsAs When you started the topic isn't actually an answer to my question. You are running under a SecurityManager (why?) and you have an AccessControlException that says you haven't granted yourself a certain permission in your .policy file. So either do that or remove the SecurityManager.

Comment: Well, if i remove the SecurityManager, the server works, but now the client says: `Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servernew.C (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)`

Comment: @AsAs So you need to deploy that class to the client.